# SQL query rails, how to filter our current reservation

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

For an hotel app, I'm trying to filter out all available accommodations for a given arrival and departure date, so a user only sees these as options.

The way I currently go about it, is by identifying all unavailable accommodations first and then deducting them from all accommodations.

**Question**

When I want to edit a reservation, I would like to:

- exclude the current reservation when evaluating available accommodations

*==> so in `@unavailable_accommodations`, the reservation and its accommodation for the `reservation.arrival` and `reservation.departure` are not evaluated in the query statement*

Is this possible, or how else can I achieve to only get available accommodations for a giver arrival and departure without taking the current reservation.accommodation into account?

**Example desired outcome**

- Say reservation_1 books accommodation_1 from Jan 1 to Jan 2.
- Then there is reservation_2 which books accommodation_1 from Jan 5 to Jan 6.
- When I subsequently edit reservation_1 and alter the departure to Jan 6, accommodation_1 should **not** be marked as available as reservation_2 already booked this accommodation

**Code**

models

```
class Reservation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :hotel
  belongs_to :accommodation
end

class Accommodation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :accommodation_category
  has_many :reservations, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :accommodation_category
end

class Hotel < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :accommodation_categories, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :accommodations, through: :accommodation_categories
  has_many :reservations, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Query

```
@unavailable_accommodations = Accommodation.joins(:reservations).where(reservations: {hotel: hotel}).where("reservations.arrival <= ? AND ? <= reservations.departure", arrival, departure)
.or(Accommodation.joins(:reservations).where(reservations: {hotel: hotel}).where("reservations.arrival >= ? AND ? >= reservations.departure", arrival, departure)).distinct
```

controller action

```
def accommodations_availability
#check if there was an accommodation for this reservation
    if !params[:reservation].nil?
      reservation = Reservation.find(params[:reservation])
      @prev_accommodation = reservation.accommodation
      @previous_cat = @prev_accommodation.accommodation_category
    end
    hotel = Hotel.includes(:accommodations).find(params[:id])
    arrival = Date.parse(accommodation_params[:arrival])
    departure = Date.parse(accommodation_params[:departure])
    time_span = arrival..departure

    #SQL statement
    @unavailable_accommodations = Accommodation.joins(:reservations).where(reservations: {hotel: hotel}).where("reservations.arrival <= ? AND ? <= reservations.departure", arrival, departure)
    .or(Accommodation.joins(:reservations).where(reservations: {hotel: hotel}).where("reservations.arrival >= ? AND ? >= reservations.departure", arrival, departure)).distinct


    @hotel_cats = hotel.accommodation_categories
    @hotel_accos = Accommodation.where(accommodation_category: @hotel_cats)
    @accommodations = @hotel_accos - @unavailable_accommodations
    @available_cats = []
    @accommodations.each do |acco|
      if !@available_cats.include? acco.accommodation_category
        @available_cats << acco.accommodation_category
      end
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

Comment: What about "Accommodation.joins(:reservations).where.not(reservations: { id: current_reservation_id })"?

Comment: @Jean-MichelGigault, thanks for your response. It should include the current reservation, as the dates for the current reservation should be available in edit.

Comment: OK I think tbh, it is an issue with your design i.e. you are calculating `available_accommodations` in the query but what you actually are showing the user is `available_reservations`. Which is why it is so confusing to visualize the issue in mind. I hope you think from this point of view. You do not necessarily need to change the design (you can show the user as available accommodations but the query should be more about reservations behind the scene).

Comment: You're right, it's about the reservations belonging to each accommodation  and consequently I would like to display the available accommodations.

Comment: @ARK, used your suggested approach and started with all_reservations with an overlap and consequently iterated over them to get the accommodations. Thanks!

Comment: ah so glad we reached a solution :) Happy Coding

Comment: On a side note, you are a very good stackoverflow user; to-the-point question, provided all details, waited patiently on your own question, started bounty, reached the solution yourself with hints and ideas i.e. we constructed the solution together. That is what community is all about. Feeling happy with what we achieved, although not that complex :)

Comment: My bad, I thought you were implementing a validation. That's why I proposed a way to exclude the current reservation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do this simply:

```
@current_reservation = Reservation.find(params[:id]) # whatever it is
@unavailable_accommodations = your_query1
@available_accommodations = your_query2 - [@current_reservation.accommodation]
```

**UPDATE:**

There can be a solution at the controller end but I have a feeling that such thing should be handled at the front-end too.

Suggestion: How about you pass the current_accommodation's previous reservation departure and next reservation arrival along when populating the update form. That way you can restrict the edit TimeDate fields by adding min and max values to both. I hope you get the idea.

Adding back-end check would still be important from design (security) point of view. I will think more about it and update again, hopefully :)

**Update 2:** (comment below question)

"OK I think tbh, it is an issue with your design i.e. you are calculating available_accommodations in the query but what you actually are showing the user is available_reservations. Which is why it is so confusing to visualize the issue in mind. I hope you think from this point of view. You do not necessarily need to change the design (you can show the user as available accommodations but the query should be more about reservations behind the scene)."

Comment: Thanks for your response. This wouldn't work. Say ```reservation_1``` books ```accommodation_1``` from Jan 1 to Jan 2. Then there is ```reservation_2``` which books ```accommodation_1``` from Jan 5 to Jan 6. When I subsequently edit ```reservation_1``` and alter the ```departure``` to Jan 6, ```accommodation_1``` would still be marked as available even tough ```reservation_2``` already booked this accommodation.

Comment: What I understand from your comment is that you want to stop user from updating reservation if it falls on to another reservation. In that case, you should also be passing `@reservations` along with `@available_accommodations` and accommodations should show "unreserved" dates as available instead of open as all. Am I missing something?

Comment: To clarify:  if someone wants to edit a reservation and fills in a different arrival or departure date, the shown controller action will be used to find all the available accommodations for those new arrival and departure dates.

Comment: Can you share your controller action code here (where you are invoking this query). I think the problem is there. I understand your requirement completely now. Just need to see the code.

Comment: Sure, will add it.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out all available accommodations directly in one query:

```rb
@available_accommodations = Accommodation.joins(
"LEFT OUTER JOIN accommodations
 ON (reservations.hotel_id = accommodations.hotel.id
     AND reservations.accommodation_id = accommodations.id
     AND reservations.arrival <= ?
     AND reservations.departure >= ?)", departure, arrival)
.where("accommodations.hotel_id = ?", params[:id])
.where("reservations.id IS NULL")
.select("accommodations.*")
```

The key point is the join conditions `reservations.arrival <= departure AND reservations.departure >= arrival`. It means only join accommodations with reservations's arrival or departure in the range of queried arrival and departure.
And then it filter out available accommodations with `reservations.id IS NULL` in joined table.